# How to make QRadioButton to "read-only"?

Tags: c++, qt5

I want to use QRadioButton for displaying some state, which cannot be changed by the user; i.e. to use it in a "read-only mode". Which is better to use:
setCheckable() or empty functionality of    click()?

Comment: `button.setEnabled(false)`?

Comment: Subclass QRadioButton and override its virtual method QRadioButton::hitButton(const QPoint & pos) const with **return false;** in it

Comment: UI Observation: I can't help but point out that buttons are meant to be pressed. I appreciate that you want to display something that can't be changed but do you not think there's a possibility that the user might think that in some circumstances they may be able to change it? i.e. if certain other conditions applied such as permissions. I'd be tempted to look at a different control to enforce the universally read-only feel.

Comment: If you don't want to use the functionnality of a radio button, don't use a radio button...

Comment: setCheckable and setEnabled are the ones that suits your definition. Why are you wasting your cpu resources with a signal that does nothing ?

Comment: @Component 10 I am making a processor simulator, so those radiobuttons are pressed, but by the processor, rather than the user. So, I am using !part' of its functionality. But, if you offer an alternative control widget ...

Comment: @undoI am using !part! of its functionality.

Comment: @ Muhammet Ali Asan  setCheckable() disables also setting radiobutton programmatically (i.e. not only the user, but also the processor cannot set it; i.e. it is not applicable for displaying a 0/1 state). setEnabled() changes the graphic appearance to gray on gray, so it is hard to notice a change. BTW I think that the computer time is wasted only when the user clicks on it, and also I guess that a good compiler optimizes out the call to a body-less procedure.

Comment: @katang: I would tend to use a plain label, an icon or some other non-interactable control if there is no user input allowed, as this enforces that the user cannot change it. I cannot comment specifically on your application naturally as contextually, a radio button may be most appropriate, though programmatically, a non-interactable control would seem easier to implement.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin overriding hitButton wouldn't prevent the user activating it with the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable mouse event by:

```cpp
wgt->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents, true);
```

When enabled, this attribute disables the delivery of mouse events to the widget and its children. Mouse events are delivered to other widgets as if the widget and its children were not present in the widget hierarchy; mouse clicks and other events effectively "pass through" them. This attribute is disabled by default.