# Disable QTRadioButton click

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to diable the click on radio buttons from the user - so that they only can be changed from the code. I have tried with this connection without any effect (it gets triggered through):

```
connect(ui->radioButton, &QRadioButton::clicked, [this]() {
        return true;
    });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: FYI: [SO: How to make QRadioButton to “read-only”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35651905/7478597)

Comment: Another option (I found in qtforum.de - German): You may use a label with two pixmaps for checked/unchecked state. For convenience, you could even derive your own class from `QLabel` to automate this.

Comment: In our S/W, we derived the `QCheckBox`/`QRadioButton` which just reset the value in the `clicked()` handlers to the previous state if editing is disabled. Of course, a separate member variable is used to store this state which may appear redundant but makes it robust and reliable.